# morphTargetInfluences With MeshRefractionMaterial from @react-three/drei

Tags: three.js, shader, webgl, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using MeshRefractionMaterial shader on a diamond geometry, and I have trying to update the morph influences, the problem is i think that the shader is overlapping with the morphs because when i am updating the morph target nothing changes but when i remove MeshRefractionMaterial and use standard material morphs are being updated does anyone have an idea how i could solve this issue?
and could anyone invite me to a discord channel maybe someone can help me there

i want to use MeshRefractionMaterial with morph influence